# DataContractSerializer for an inline array

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-8, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I need to serialize and deserialize the following XML for a Windows app (it is an existing API, already handled fine by iOS and Android apps). Please note the multiple items:

```xml
<parameters>
  <source>home</source>
  <day>today</day>
  <item><name>foo</name></item>
  <item><name>bar</name></item>
  <item><name>baz</name></item>
</parameters>
```

So I made this class:

```cs
[DataContract(Name = "parameters", Namespace = "")]
internal class Parameters
{
    [DataMember(Name = "source", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 0)]
    public string Source;

    [DataMember(Name = "day", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
    public string Day;

    [DataMember(Name = "item", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 2)]
    public Item[] Items;
}

[DataContract(Name = "item", Namespace = "")]
internal class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 0)]
    public string Name;
}
```

My code with `DataContractSerializer` is:

```
// Serialization:
using (var streamObject = new MemoryStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(streamObject))
{
    var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    ser.WriteObject(streamObject, objForSerialization);
    streamObject.Position = 0;
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}

[...]

// Deserialization:
using (var streamObject = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlData)))
{
    var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)ser.ReadObject(streamObject);
}
```

But the resulting serialization is not what I need:

```xml
<parameters>
  <source>home</source>
  <day>today</day>
  <item>
    <item><name>foo</name></item>
    <item><name>bar</name></item>
    <item><name>baz</name></item>
  </item>
</parameters>
```

And it won't let me deserialize the first example!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement IXmlSerializable yourself and create a custom xml since you dont want the beginning and end attribute of your array.

otherwise, you would just have to use a bunch of Item properties, which isn't smart..

Comment: *bunch of Item properties*, you mean like `[DataMember(Name = "item")] Item Item1;[DataMember(Name = "item")] Item Item2; ...`? Then it would only handle a fixed amount of items.

Comment: Yes, it would only handle a fixed amount, that is why i said it isnt smart. Implementing IXmlSerializable lets you choose how your xml output will be, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Giving details about how I implemented IXmlSerializable in the end:

```
[XmlRoot("parameters")]
internal class Parameters
{
    public string Source;

    public string Day;

    public List<Item> Items;

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        Source = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("source", "");
        Day = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("day", "");

        var newItems = new List<Item>();
        while (reader.LocalName == "item")
        {
            var newItem = new Item();
            newItem.ReadXml(reader);
            newItems.Add(newItem);
        }
        Items = newItems;
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("source", Source);
        writer.WriteElementString("day", Day);

        foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");
            item.WriteXml(writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

I dislike the fact IXmlSerializable was quite lengthy and incompatible with DataContract, although.